# Parsing invalid characters to XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, clr

the application idea is simple , the application is given a path , and application writes each file`s path into XML , the problem i am facing is the file name can have invalid character and that makes the application stops working , here is the code i use to parse file information into XML :

```
    // the collecting details method
    private void Get_Properties(string path)
    {
        // Load the XML File
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load("Details.xml");

        foreach (string eachfile in Files)
        {
            try
            {
                FileInfo Info = new FileInfo(eachfile);

                toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Adding : " + Info.Name;

                // Create the Root element
                XmlElement ROOT = xml.CreateElement("File");

                if (checkBox1.Checked)
                {
                    XmlElement FileName = xml.CreateElement("FileName");
                    FileName.InnerText = Info.Name;
                    ROOT.AppendChild(FileName);
                }

                if (checkBox2.Checked)
                {
                    XmlElement FilePath = xml.CreateElement("FilePath");
                    FilePath.InnerText = Info.FullName;
                    ROOT.AppendChild(FilePath);
                }

                if (checkBox3.Checked)
                {
                    XmlElement ModificationDate = xml.CreateElement("ModificationDate");
                    string lastModification = Info.LastAccessTime.ToString();
                    ModificationDate.InnerText = lastModification;
                    ROOT.AppendChild(ModificationDate);
                }

                if (checkBox4.Checked)
                {
                    XmlElement CreationDate = xml.CreateElement("CreationDate");
                    string Creation = Info.CreationTime.ToString();
                    CreationDate.InnerText = Creation;
                    ROOT.AppendChild(CreationDate);
                }

                if (checkBox5.Checked)
                {
                    XmlElement Size = xml.CreateElement("Size");
                    Size.InnerText = Info.Length.ToString() + " Bytes";
                    ROOT.AppendChild(Size);
                }

                xml.DocumentElement.InsertAfter(ROOT, xml.DocumentElement.LastChild);

                // +1 step in progressbar
                toolStripProgressBar1.PerformStep();
                success_counter++;
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                toolStripProgressBar1.PerformStep();

                error_counter++;
            }
        }

        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Now Writing the Details File";

        xml.Save("Details.xml");

        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = success_counter + " Items has been added and "+ error_counter +" Items has Failed , Total Files Processed ("+Files.Count+")";

        Files.Clear();
    }
```

Here is how the XML looks like after Generation of details :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Files>
  <File>
    <FileName>binkw32.dll</FileName>
    <FilePath>D:\ALL DLLS\binkw32.dll</FilePath>
    <ModificationDate>3/31/2012 5:13:56 AM</ModificationDate>
    <CreationDate>3/31/2012 5:13:56 AM</CreationDate>
    <Size>286208 Bytes</Size>
  </File>
 <File>
```

Example of characters i would like to parse to XML without issue :

BX]GC^O^_nI_C{jv_rbp&1b_H âo&psolher d) doိiniᖭ

icon_Áq偩侉₳㪏ံ�ぞ鵃_䑋屡1]

MAnaFor줡�

EDIT [PROBLEM SOLVED]

All i had to do is : 
1- convert the file name to UTF8-Bytes
2- Convert the UTF8-Bytes back to string

Here is the method :

```
byte[] FilestoBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Info.Name);
string utf8 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(FilestoBytes);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the xml is malformed. Xml files can not have some characters without being escaped.
For example, this is not valid:

```
<dummy>You & Me</dummy>
```

Instead you should use:

```
<dummy>You &amp; Me</dummy>
```

Illegal characters in XML are &, < and > (as well as " or ' in attributes)

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear which of your characters you're having problems with. So long as you use the XML API (instead of trying to write the XML out directly yourself) you *should* be fine with any valid text (broken surrogate pairs would probably cause an issue) but what *won't* be valid is Unicode code points less than space (U+0020), aside from tab, carriage return and line feed. They're simply not catered for in XML.

Answer (score 1):

Illegal characters in XML are &, < and > (as well as " or ' in attributes)

In file system on windows you can have only & and ' in the file name (<,>," are not allowed in file name)

While saving XML you can escape these characters. For example for & you will require `&amp;`